Density of numbers with a large prime factor in specified arithmetic progression
I am looking for an answer to the following question.
Fix some coprime integers $a$ and $b$ and let $S_x$ be the set of positive integers $n<x$ such that there exists a prime factor $p$ of $n$ with $p \equiv a \mod b$ and $p>\log(x)^{(1+\delta)}$.
Then does the limit of $|S_x|/x$ approach $1$ as $x$ approaches infinity.
This comes from trying to modify the paper "On Large Cyclic Subgroups of Finite Groups" by E. Bertram to prove a density result for a different class of groups. I have checked computationally and the answer definitely seems to be yes, but I'm still unable to prove it satisfactorily.

The answer is yes, since the set of numbers in $[1.x]$ which are $(\log x)^{1 + \delta}$-smooth have density $0$. See for example equation (1.14) in these notes: https://dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/msrire.pdf

@StanleyYaoXiao That doesn't address the condition $p \equiv a \pmod{b}$.

The same second moment argument, the one that shows almost all $n$ have $\bigl(1+o(1)\bigr)\log\log n$ distinct prime factors, shows that almost all $n$ have $\bigl(\frac{1}{\phi(b)}+o(1)\bigr)\log\log n$ distinct prime factors $p$ that satisfy $p \equiv a \pmod{b}$ and $p > (\log n)^{1+\delta}$. In particular, almost all $n$ have at least one such prime factor.
Indeed, letting $$R := \sum_{\substack{p \in [Y,Z) \\ p \equiv a \pmod{b}}} \frac{1}{p},$$ we have
$$\frac{1}{X}\sum_{n \le X} \sum_{\substack{p \in [Y,Z) \\ p \equiv a \pmod{b}}} 1_{p \mid n} = R+O\Bigl(\frac{Z^2}{X}\Bigr)$$
$$\frac{1}{X}\sum_{n \le X} \Bigl(\sum_{\substack{p \in [Y,Z) \\ p \equiv a \pmod{b}}} 1_{p \mid n}\Bigr)^2 = R^2+R+O\Bigl(\frac{Z^4}{X}\Bigr)+O\Bigl(\frac{1}{Y}\Bigr).$$
Therefore, setting $Y = (\log X)^{1+\delta}$ and $Z = X^{1/10}$, a second moment argument shows almost all positive integers $n \le X$ have $R \pm O(R^{1/2+\epsilon})$ distinct prime factors $p \in [Y,Z)$ with $p \equiv a \pmod{b}$. It remains to note $R \to \infty$, in fact, $R = \bigl(\frac{1}{\phi(b)}+o(1)\bigr)\log\log X$.

Just a remark that this argument is essentially reproducing a special case of the Turan-Kubilius inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%E2%80%93Kubilius_inequality , specialized to the additive function that counts the number of prime factors $p$ with $p = a \hbox{ mod } p$ and $p \geq \log^{1+\delta} x$, in say the range $x/2 \leq n \leq x$.

Thanks for the answer. Apologies for the basic question, this is not my field at all. By second moment argument do you mean an application of the inequality $\Pr(W>0)\ge E[X]^2/E[X^2]$, where W is the random variable which is $1$ when $n$ satisfies the conditions I want? So that by the two equalities you listed we should have $\Pr(W>0)\rightarrow 1$ as $X\rightarrow \infty$.

@AsksQuestionsAboutMath I'm using Chebyshev's inequality: $\Pr[|Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]| \ge \lambda] \le \frac{1}{\lambda^2} \mathbb{E}[|Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]|^2]$. We are applying this to $Y$ being the random variable obtained by choosing $n$ randomly from ${1,\dots,X}$ and then looking at $\sum_{\substack{p \in [Y,Z) \ p \equiv a \pmod{b}}} 1_{p \mid n}$. We use $\lambda = R^{1/2+\epsilon}$, where $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary (if you want, $\epsilon := 1/10$).

@mathworker21 Ah I see! Thanks.

@mathworker21 Thanks again for the reply. It turned out this method worked for what we were eventually trying to prove so it has ended up being included in a paper which is currently being written up. Would you like to be included in a reference as the person  who suggested this approach? If so please let me know and we can get in contact somehow to share details. Thanks.

@AsksQuestionsAboutMath Hi, sorry for late response. No need to thank me, I'm sure this argument is standard.

@mathworker21 ok great, no worries then.
